# Ubuntu 15.10 upgrade

Tags: windows, 15.10

Hai I have windows  10 alongside Ubuntu 15.04 I have Ubuntu 15.10 update available but if I upgrade Ubuntu to 15.10 then will my windows 10 partition gets deleted ?

Comment: No. It will not get deleted.

Comment: It will not. However you should ALWAYS do a backup before installing any OS... just in case.

Answer (score 2):

If during the upgrade you use the boot to delete other partitions - then yes, but that is not a default setting, and there shouldn't be any reason for that to happen.

Just pay attention to what software you're activating, and at what level.
You might find this helpful:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UpgradeFromOldVersion